# PHP Run a Curl Function in Foreach Loop

Tags: php, curl, foreach

I have to send out SMS in multiples of 150 batch per CURL post. Here is my code,

```
$mobiles = "9844700001,9844700002,9844700003,9844700004;9844700005
 9844700006,9844700007,9844700008,9844700009,9844700010,.... upto 1000 numbers"
$rmobiles = preg_split('/[\ \n\r\;\:\,]+/', $mobiles, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
if(count($rmobiles) <= 1000){
    foreach($rmobiles as $key => $value){
        if ($key % 150 == 0) {
            //Generate a new random ID
            $randno = rand(0,10000);
        }
        $this->addtoDB("00000", $value, $randno);
    } 
    return $this->sendmsms($randno);
} else {
    echo "error, max 1000";
}
```

Since `sendmsms` function is outside the foreach loop, it only sends out the last batch with the random number and if I include `sendmsms` function within foreach loop then the function will run as many mobile numbers are there.

How should I able to run `sendmsms` function based on generated `randno` and so that my curl function `sendmsms` will run properly and generate db records genuinely.

### Edit

I again tried like this, but its inserting single record in my DB.

```
    foreach($rmobiles as $key => $value){
        if ($key % 150 == 0) {
            //Generate a new random ID
            $randno = rand(0,10000);
        }
        $this->addtoDB("00000", $value, $randno);
        if ($key % 150 == 0) {
            return $this->sendmsms($randno);
        }
    }
```

### Edit 2

I even tried creating array for randno. But only first batch is going, not the all 7 batches.

```
    $arr = array();
    foreach($rmobiles as $key => $value){
        if ($key % 150 == 0) {
            //Generate a new random ID
            $randno = rand(0,10000);
            $arr[] = $randno;
        }
        $this->addtoDB("00000", $value, $randno);
    }
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){
        return $this->sendmsms($v);
    }
```

When I echo it, it perfectly displays but through DB its going just 1 batch. What could be the reason?

Comment: Move `sendmsms` into `if ($key)`?

Comment: This is not linked to [tag:batch-file]; please read the tag info!

Comment: Good point, I once thought but wanted to get experts answer here, will try and update, thanks

Comment: @aschipfl sorry, I must have clicked on all the recommended tags by SO.

Comment: u_mulder, since I need to return the sendmsms function, once it returns then `addtoDB` function wont run. I have to run the function afer `addtoDB` function. I will try again after addtoDB with if($key) %150 by repeating. Will that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that comes to mind is using [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to break $rmobiles into multiple arrays with a maximum of 150 elements each. Not sure if your sendmsms function takes a string or an array, but something like this may get you on the right track:

```
$mobiles = "9844700001,9844700002,9844700003,9844700004;...";
$rmobiles = preg_split('/[\ \n\r\;\:\,]+/', $mobiles, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach (array_chunk($rmobiles, 150) as $batch) {
    $this->sendmsms(implode(',',$batch));
}
```

Comment: No, since it has to go through all db insertion, adding/debiting balance, updating provider response, the given solution wont be much of a help.

Comment: Edited my question, what should be the problem for my edited try?

Comment: Okay, finally got it solved. In my 2nd try, I was using `return` hence it was delivering either the first batch or last batch. I later realised after looking at your code that I have been using `return`. So thanks to you. And since your answer hinted me at the right path, I am accepting your answer. If you could also update with the outcome, others should benefit. Thanks again.